# How to initialize all methods inside a namespace?namespaces javascript INITIALIZING ALL methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, namespaces, initialization

Maybe this is a simple question but I could not find anything on google or this site.
So if I have

```
var myNamespace = {

    foo: function() {
    },

    bar: function() {
    }
};
```

how would i load both foo() and bar() without having to do it one by one, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        myNamespace.foo();
        myNamespace.bar();
        .
        .
        .
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tested this, but something like this should prove useful.
Every function in JavaScript has a `call()` method for invoking it. Then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(myNamespace, function(index, obj) {
    if (typeof(obj) == 'function')
    {
       obj.call(myNamespace);
    }
  });
});
```

If you need to replace the `this` scope reference, you could patch this up with `jQuery.proxy`.

Comment: 1. `'Function'` should be `'function'`. 2. You need to provide the context `namespace` to the `call` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var k in namespace) {
    if (typeof namespace[k] === 'function') {
        namespace[k]();    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail if something in the namespace isn't a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
var func;

for (func in namespace) {
   if (namespace.hasOwnProperty(func) {
       if (typeof namespace == 'Function') {
           namespace[func]();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to use reserved word `function` as a variable name.